# Javascript func.prototype.apply() with a string instead of `this`

Tags: javascript

Just noticed a strange thing-

```js
function one(){
  console.log(this);
}
function two(arg){
  one.apply(arg);
}

two("Hello World");
```

Now it returns a `String` object containing all the letters of the argument [checked in the browser console]. I know I should have passed `this` as the first argument of `apply` and an `array` as the second. I did this accidentally and now I'm curious why is this happening. Can someone explain please? Or at least point me to the right direction?

Thanks in advance. And sorry for being so naive.

Comment: The `this` value must always be an object - AFAICR what's happened is that `[[ToObject]]` will have been invoked, and what I'm seeing in Chrome is the same as if I call: `console.log(new String("Hello World"))`

Comment: Because you didn't provide the context **this** inside your **two** function, the *args* will serve as the context **this**, which is passed as the variable *this* to your *one* function. That's why you see `[Hello World]` in the console.

Remember that *args* in your *two* function is an array-like object (not an array by definition), explaining the output of `[Hello World]`;

Comment: thank you every one. I was missing this `console.log(new String())` part. Thats why I've become confused.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In JavaScript, any value passed as `this` will be coerced to an object.

Thus, for a primitive string variable, `this` is essentially `new String("Hello World")`, which is a string wrapper object with all characters assigned as properties (similar to an array).

```js
console.log("Hello World")

console.log(new String("Hello World"))
```

For more information, see [the distinction between string primitives and String objects](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String#Distinction_between_string_primitives_and_String_objects) on MDN.